# Are there reasons to avoid handling all routes in a Node/Express app with an asterisk?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a basic node app that catches all incoming requests:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  //handle GET request with specific parameter
}
```

Is there a reason to avoid this catchall if the app is only looking to handle a specific GET request. I'm guessing this approach might increase server load by handling anything directed at it.

If so, what would be the optimal way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you *want* the wildcard if you only care about a specific route? That's just making you do the work of figuring out if you want to handle any given request. If you really want to handle that yourself, you might as well ditch Express and use `http.createServer`.

Comment: I was thinking of it mainly as a way to avoid error handling code for requests other than the one I was looking for.